# Working of Pointers

Tags: c, pointers

> Practice.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{    
  int a=6,*x;

  x=&a;
  printf("\n  Value of A = %d",a);
  printf("\n  Value of X = %u",x);
  x=x+2;
  printf("\nNew Value of X = %u",x);
  printf("\nValue at address stored in X = %d",*x);

  return 0;
}
```

Output of the above stated code is as follows :

```
                  Value of A = 6
                  Value of X = 2686680
              New Value of X = 2686688
Value at address stored in X = 16
```

I re-wrote the code for `Practice.c` from beginning with new variables and new values.

> `Practice.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{    
  int i=8,*p;

  p=&i;
  printf("\n  Value of I = %d",a);
  printf("\n  Value of P = %u",x);
  p=p+2;
  printf("\nNew Value of P = %u",x);
  printf("\nValue at address stored in P = %d",*x);

  return 0;
}
```

Output of the above code is :

```
                  Value of I = 8
                  Value of P = 2686680
              New Value of P = 2686688
Value at address stored in P = 16
```

This `4th` line in the output remained the same, even after I kept on changing the variable and its respective value.
So I deleted `Practice.c` and wrote a new program named `Test.c` with same code & format as `Practice.c`.

> Test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{    
  int a=6,*x;

  x=&a;
  printf("\n  Value of A = %d",a);
  printf("\n  Value of X = %u",x);
  x=x+2;
  printf("\nNew Value of X = %u",x);
  printf("\nValue at address stored in X = %d",*x);

  return 0;
}
```

> Output of `Test.c` is as follows :

```
                  Value of A = 6
                  Value of X = 2686680
              New Value of X = 2686688
Value at address stored in X = 2686723
```

Now, when I re-wrote the `Test.c` from beginning with new variable, the output of the program is as follows :

```
                  Value of I = 8
                  Value of P = 2686680
              New Value of P = 2686688
Value at address stored in P = 2686723
```

Again the`4th` line of the output remains the same.

> Questions

1- Is the value in the `4th` line `Garbage Value`, if it is than why is this value remains the same no matter how many times we change the variable, while using under the same file name?

2- Why is the value of the `4th` line changes when we save the same code under a different file name?

Comment: You should use `%p` to print the value of a pointer, and cast it to `void *`

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Do u mind elaborating ur idea little bit, please. Because I didn't get it. The `void *` part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program exhibits undefined behaviour because there is no reason at all to believe that `x+2` is the address of an object of type `int`. Your program could do anything. It just so happens that it prints out that particular value. But it might equally well fail with a segmentation fault.

> Why does this value remains the same no matter how many times we change the variable?

Putting aside the undefined behaviour for a moment, it's hardly surprising that changing the value of one memory location has no influence on the value at another. Why would you expect that changing `x[0]` would have any impact on `x[1]`?

There's not really all that much to be gained by reasoning about undefined behaviour. You could study the compiled program under a debugger and no doubt work out what the compiler/linker has placed at that address. But almost any change could disturb the behaviour.